# How should one think to get the radius of the resulting curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For example, the curve C is given as the intersection between 
$$
C: x²+y²+z²=1, x+y+z=0
$$
Radius: 1

Another one:
$$
C: x²+y²+z²=1, x+y=1
$$

Radius:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

How should I think to get these? I know they're ellipses, but substituting them into each other yields "hard" expressions.

Comment: You only get an ellipse when you project the curve (which is a circle) into the $xy$-plane. Only when the plane is parallel to the $xy$-plane is the ellipse a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane at distance $d$ from the center of a sphere of radius $R$ intersects the sphere by a circle of radius $\sqrt{R^2-d^2}$ (This is just the old good Pythagorean theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The two examples given above are circles. Unless the coefficients of $x^2,y^2,z^2$ are not identical, the intersection would remain as circles.

The first equation gives a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the second equation gives plane.
I would tackle this problem by finding the distance from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the plane. Then by simple geometry computation you can find the radius of the circle.

Notice the equation of plane is given by
$$\boldsymbol{n\cdot(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_0)} = \boldsymbol{0},$$
why is it? The argument is given [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx).

By picking a convenient $\boldsymbol{r}_0$, you can find $\boldsymbol{n}$, along this direction, you can find the distance between the origin and the plane.

Now you know the radius of the unit ball and you know the distance to the cutting plane, by Pythagorean you can find the radius of the circle.